# After click on like button the whole website become disappear but after refresh the webpage it increments why does it happens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am working with a video application website with a fake json server. Everything is going well but the problem appears while I want to like a video it becomes disappears and throwing an error: `Objects are not valid as react child`. Why this is happening?

The whole state slice:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { getVideo, updateReaction } from "./videoApi"

//initializing the state
const initialState = {
    video: {}, //while we are going to push a single video into the state we should put it an object instance...
    loading: false,
    isError: false, 
    error: ''
}

// async thunk for getting single video
export const fetchVideo = createAsyncThunk('vidoes/fetchVideo', async (id) => {
    const videos = await getVideo(id);
    return videos;
});

// another async thunk to react on a single video (like or dislike)
export const fetchReact = createAsyncThunk('video/reaction', async ({ id, reaction }) => {
    const videoReaction = await updateReaction({ id, reaction })
    return videoReaction;
})

//creating slice 
const videoSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'video',
    initialState,
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchVideo.pending, (state) => {
            state.loading = true;
            state.isError = false;
        })

        builder.addCase(fetchVideo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.video= action.payload;
        })

        builder.addCase(fetchVideo.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.error = action.error?.message;
            state.video = [];
        })

        //writing codes for emplementing like funcitonality 
        builder.addCase(fetchReact.pending, (state) => {
            return state;
        })

        builder.addCase(fetchReact.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.video.likes = action.payload;
            state.video.unlikes = action.payload;
        })

        builder.addCase(fetchReact.rejected, (state) => {
            return state;
        })

    }
});

export default videoSlice.reducer;
```

This one is video api

```
import axios from '../../utils/axios'

export const getVideo = async (id) => {
  const response = await axios.get(`/videos/${id}`)
  return response.data;
}

export const updateReaction = async ({ id, reaction }) => {
  console.log(id)
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/videos/${id}`)
  if (data) {
    let updatedReaction =
      reaction === 'like'
        ? {
          likes: data.likes + 1,
        }
        : {
          unlikes: data.unlikes + 1,
        };

    const response = await axios.patch(`/videos/${id}`, updatedReaction);
    return response.data;
  }
}
```

Video description component

```
import LIke from '../Like/LIke';

const VidoeDescription = ({ video }) => {
    const { title, date, description, likes, unlikes, id } = video;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="text-lg font-semibold tracking-tight text-slate-800">
                {title}
            </h1>
            <div className="pb-4 flex items-center space-between border-b">
                <h2 className="text-sm leading-[1.7142857] text-slate-600 w-full">
                    Uploaded on {date}
                </h2>
                <LIke likes={likes} unlikes={unlikes} id={id} />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4 text-sm text-[#334155] dark:text-slate-400">
                {description}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default VidoeDescription;
```

Like component where I put my like and unlike component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import LikeImg from '../../assets/like.svg';
import UnLikeImg from '../../assets/unlike.svg'
// import { updateReaction } from '../../features/video/videoApi';
import { fetchReact } from '../../features/video/video_slice';

const LIke = ({ likes, unlikes, id }) => {
    console.log(id)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    //handle like features
    const reactionHandler = ({ id, reaction }) => {
        dispatch(fetchReact({ id, reaction }))
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex gap-10 w-48">
            <div className="flex gap-1">
                <div
                    className="shrink-0 cursor-pointer"
                    onClick={() => reactionHandler({ id, reaction: 'like' })}
                >
                    <img className="w-5 block" src={LikeImg} alt="Like" />
                </div>
                <div className="text-sm leading-[1.7142857] text-slate-600">
                    {likes >= 1000 ? `${ likes }K` : likes}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex gap-1">
                <div
                    onClick={() => reactionHandler({ id, reaction: 'unlike' })}
                    className="shrink-0 cursor-pointer"
                >
                    <img className="w-5 block" src={UnLikeImg} alt="Unlike" />
                </div>
                <div className="text-sm leading-[1.7142857] text-slate-600">
                    {unlikes >= 1000 ? `${ unlikes }K` : unlikes}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LIke;
```

This one is root video page

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Player from '../component/Player/Player';
import VidoeDescription from '../component/VideoDescription/VidoeDescription';
import { fetchVideo } from '../features/video/video_slice';
import Loading from '../component/Loading/Loading';
import RelatedVideo from '../component/VideoList/RelatedVideo';

const Videos = () => {
    const { loading, isError, video, error } = useSelector(state => state.video)
    const { id, link, title , tags } = video || {};
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { videoId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchVideo(videoId))
    }, [dispatch, videoId])

    //decide what to render in the ui
    let content = null;
    if (loading) {
        content = <Loading />
    }

    if (loading && isError) {
        content = <div className="col-span-12"><srong>{error}</srong></div>
    }

    if (!loading && !isError && video?.id) {
        content = <div className="col-span-12"><srong>{error}</srong></div>
    }

    if (!loading && !isError && video?.id) {
        content = <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 pb-20 min-h-[400px]">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2 lg:gap-8">
                <div className="col-span-full w-full space-y-8 lg:col-span-2">
                    <Player link={link} title={title} />
                    <VidoeDescription video={video} />
                </div>
                <RelatedVideo currentId={id} tags={tags} />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <section className="pt-6 pb-20">
                {content}
            </section>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Videos;
```

Comment: *Objects are not valid as react child* - you are trying to render a javascript object, but it's impossible in react

Comment: but which one is creating problem and why this is happening? I checked every props what I passing from one component to another component everything seems a single value I can't find the object . Could you help to find that out? But, while I refresh the page again the like buttons counter increase and the whole errors become gone.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Here:

```
builder.addCase(fetchReact.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.video.likes = action.payload;
  state.video.unlikes = action.payload;
})
```

`action.payload` looks like this:

```
{
  likes: 1,
}
```

because it's how you created it in `updateReaction`

### Solution

You wanted to do this instead:

```
builder.addCase(fetchReact.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.video.likes = action.payload.likes;
  state.video.unlikes = action.payload.unlikes;
})
```